# Alternative to scheduled tasks

Tags: amazon-web-services, windows-server

I'm moving stuff from Azure to AWS, and the only thing I'm really gonna miss is the webjobs, where I can schedule command line jobs.

I know I can achieve somewhat the same with task scheduler or windows services, but I do also like the way webjobs shows logs and that stuff...

Do anybody know a tool like that, that can run windows command line apps on AWS?

Answer (score 2):

Checkout [AWS Lambda](http://aws.amazon.com/lambda/). It is a new service from AWS.

AWS Lambda, compute service that runs your code in response to events and automatically manages the compute resources for you, making it easy to build applications that respond quickly to new information.

[Lambda vs WebJobs](http://sonnn2.com/2014/11/aws-vs-azure-lambda-vs-webjobs/)

Comment: AWS Lambda doesn't support .net or windows command line apps.

Comment: Newer versions of Lamba include support for C#. I'm not sure how long ago it was added. I think they also have a way to call executables.